# renice doesn't work in macOS Sierra

Tags: shell, nice

I wanted set low priority to `HandBrake` in macOS.

I tried to use `renice` command by `pid`, but it seems not working. (nice value stays `0`)

```
% ps ax -l | grep Hand
  501 32255     1   0  46  0  3433240 544536 -      R      ??   52:50.69 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
% sudo renice -p 32255 -n 10
% ps ax -l | grep Hand
  501 32255     1   0  46  0  3433240 530868 -      R      ??   55:58.62 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
% sudo renice -p 32255
% ps ax -l | grep Hand
  501 32255     1   0  46  0  3433184 520424 -      R      ??   62:01.50 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
```

It works by using `nice` like this.

```
% nice /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
% ps ax -l | grep Hand
501 32467 30511   0  46 10  2726256 156284 -      SN+  s004    0:00.67 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/renice.8.html):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> renice priority [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
> renice -n increment [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
> ```

It looks like `-n` and argument should come before `-p`.
So try:

```
sudo renice -n 10 -p 32255
```

Certainly this is the way I do it on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Hi does this still work for you on mac 10.13.4? Your method described above does not seem to have any effect for me (i asked a related question a while ago but got no answers) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442470/mac-10-13-4-renice-seems-to-have-no-effect?noredirect=1#comment801007_442470

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy on he face of it it still works. But having read your question I couldn’t say whether it is effective.