# macOS 10.13.4 - `renice` seems to have no effect

Tags: process, macos, nice

I am trying to test out the `renice` command on my Mac, it seems to be having no effect. This is how I'm testing it:

I have a dual core CPU with hyper threading, so I run 6 instances of `node -e 'while(1){}'` which, combined, max out my CPU. (Alternatively, run `while true; do echo running > /dev/null ; done` if you don't have node.)

I then get a PID of one of the node processes, either by the activity monitor application or `pgrep`, and then run `sudo renice -n 19 -p $PID`.

By looking at the activity monitor application or `htop`, the CPU usage of all of the node processes are still equivalent:

[image]

My understanding was that the process that I `renice`d would have a low priority, and so would not use a significant amount of CPU time when there are other processes using it.

Am I misunderstanding something about `renice`? Or is this a bug in macOS?

Comment: You have four cores, and you have four running processes. Why would each not get their own core?

Comment: A nice process would still get 100% of a CPU if it was available to it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, I have 2 cores, with hyperthreading. Hyperthreading gives, on average is about 30% of a core's worth of performance. Therefore 4 threads may not (on avg) be able to run in parallel.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , @Kusalananda , I can add more `node` processes, e.g. 6, and the same effect is produced - same cpu usage. I have edited my question to show this

Comment: Have just tested this on Ubuntu. My method described above successfully lowers the CPU usage of the reniced node processes

Comment: Running some rudimentary tests I’m seeing this too on 10.13.4. The curious thing is that on my FreeBSD system the Priority of a process shifts with the niceness. On macOS the Priority remains the same, so I wonder if it is a bug. Might be worth flagging to Apple if anyone has an appropriate account.

Comment: @forquare Thank you for testing this! Given that you're the only answer in almost two weeks, do you want to move your comment into an answer and i can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running some rudimentary tests I’m seeing this too on 10.13.4.

I wrote a small C program called looper which did some basic maths in an infinite loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long long prev = 0;
    unsigned long long current = 1;
    unsigned long long total = 0;

    while(1){
        total = current + prev;
        prev = current;
        current = total;
        printf("%llu\n", total);
    }
}
```

I ran multiple copies of this on my FreeBSD box and examined them using `htop(1)`.  Using `renice(8)` I could see the Nice value being incremented, the Priority value being incremented, and the CPU percentage decreasing - expected behavior.

I ran the same program on macOS 10.13.4 and repeated the process.  While I could see the Nice value incrementing, the Priority value and CPU percentage remained consistent.

I wonder if it is a bug, I've not had cause to look this closely at Nice values in macOS before - the behavior has been close enough to what I expected that I've not been inclined to investigate.

If you have a developer account it would be worth reporting this to Apple.

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to replicate that the priority has not been increased using `ps -o pid,comm,pri,nice -p $(pgrep node)`. I've reported this to apple again on their developer bug reporter. Hopefully we get a response in any reasonable amount of time!