# `renice` seems to have no effect on CPU usage on Mac 10.13.4

Tags: process, osx, nice

I am trying to test out the `renice` command on my Mac, it seems to be having no effect. This is how I'm testing it:

I have a dual core CPU with hyper threading, so I run 6 instances of `node -e 'while(1){}'` which, combined, max out my CPU. (Alternatively, run `while true; do echo running > /dev/null ; done` if you dont have node.)

I then get a PID of one of the node processes, either by the activity monitor application or `pgrep`, and then run `sudo renice -n 19 -p $PID`.

By looking at the activity monitor application or `htop`, the CPU usage of all of the node processes are still equivalent:

[image]

My understanding was that the process that I `renice`d would have a low priority, and so would not use a significant amount of CPU time when there are other processes using it.

Am I misunderstanding something about `renice`? Or is this a bug in Mac OS?

Comment: Note: This is an intentional re-ask of this which got no responses: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442470/mac-10-13-4-renice-seems-to-have-no-effect

Comment: You received responses the first time you asked.. There's no reason to ask the same question again.